# Azure Search Index - manage indexer for when database is erase/replace every 24 hours?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We've set up an Azure Search Index on our Azure SQL Database of ~2.7 million records all contained in one Capture table.  Every night, our data scrapers grab the latest data, truncate the Capture table, then rewrite all the latest data - most of which will be duplicates of what was just truncated, but with a small amount of new data.  We don't have any feasible way of only writing new records each day, due to the large amounts of unstructured data in a couple fields of each record.

How should we best manage our index in this scenario?  Running the indexer on a schedule requires you to indicate this "high watermark column."  Because of the nature of our database (erase/replace once a day) we don't have any column that would apply here.  Further, what really needs to happen for our Azure Search Index is either it also needs to go through a full daily erase/replace, or some other approach so that we don't keep adding 2.7 million duplicate records every day to the index.  The former likely won't work for us because it takes 4 hours minimum to index our whole database.  That's 4 hours where clients (worldwide) may not have a full dataset to query on.

Can someone from Azure Search make a suggestion here?

Answer (score 1):

What's the proportion of the data that actually changes every day? If that proportion is small, then you don't need to recreate the search index. Simply `reset` the indexer after the SQL table has been recreated, and trigger reindexing (resetting an indexer clears its high water mark state, but doesn't change the target index). Even though it may take several hours, your index is still there with the mostly full dataset. Presumably if you update the dataset once a day, your clients can tolerate hours of latency for picking up latest data.

Comment: Eugene - thanks for your continued help in this area.  I'd estimate that 15-20% of any given daily dataset is new data.  So just to make sure I understand how Reset works - you're saying that by doing this, the entire index from the day before is maintained while the new one is importing?  Then once the new index is done importing, it replaces the index from the day before?

Comment: Eugene, I'm still having trouble with this and need some additional guidance.  We don't have any field in our database that is a great candidate for watermarking because of the nature of our data (erase/replace every 24 hours as mentioned above).  Therefore I don't have this set on a schedule, and have just been running it manually.  In order for me to set it on a schedule, it wants a high watermark column, and wants me to Track Changes as well.  Should I just pick any column as the watermark column then?  And should I be marking Track Deletions?